# How to correctly bind two classes in C#

Tags: c#, data-binding

I want something like this

```
Class1 { DateTime time }
Class2 { List<Class1> }
Class3 : ObservableCollection<Class2> { }
```

but I implemented this:

```
Class1 { DateTime time }
Class2 { List<DateTime> }
Class3 : ObservableCollection<Class2> { }
```

with the thought that it saves more memory. Each object's time attribute is unique. I know both solutions are wrong so, what is the correct way of binding these two objects? Can I access Class1's attributes through Class3?

EDIT: The above isn't the actual code, is just to explain my problem. The classes have other attributes and Class1 and Class2 are used elsewhere too

Comment: Let's say that is used somewhere else.

Comment: So, you want a `ObservableCollection<List<DateTime/Class1>>` ? Or do you want only a `ObservableCollection<DateTime/Class1>` to bind it to WPF?

Answer (score 2):

In your second solution, there's no way of getting to any instance of `Class1` from `Class3` with what you've shown us - you could have a load of `Class3` and `Class2` instances, but never create an instance of `Class1` at all.

If your first solution represents what you *logically* want, why not use it?

On the other hand, if your `Class1` code doesn't have *any* state apart from a `DateTime`, do you need it to exist at all?

Comment: Yes, so in my second solution I'd have to find the Class1 objects the check their time to see if it matches to the times I have in my list in Class2. With the first solution don't I have duplicate information?

Comment: @user579674: No, you don't - you just have a list of references to instances of `Class1`. Where's the duplication?

Comment: Yes you are right.. I didn't explain my problem very well. Let's say I have a list List<Class1> in my main program where I keep all Class1 objects. In this case, my first solution wouldn't require that I copy the objects to Class2?

Comment: @user579674: Well it wouldn't be copying *objects* - only *references*. Keeping those references instead of the `DateTime` values is likely to keep things simpler and more consistent, and avoids having to perform a lookup. It's important to understand that a `List<Class1>` isn't a list of `Class1` *objects* - it's a list of *references*.

Answer (score 1):

First, what problem are you trying to solve? Saving memory isn't the problem I see here. Are there millions of these objects being created that force you into this solution?

If not, please consider the most readable / maintainable solution possible. Otherwise feel free to place share your problem to place it in context for us. So we can take a closer look and provide a better answer.

Comment: Well, I need to access Class1 through Class3. I have a listbox that is binded to Class3 where I see the Class2 objects. I want in another listbox to see the Class1 objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Class1` in other places, meaning the objects already exists, then using them in a List will not need a lot of memory. It will only store a pointer to the object (4/8 Bytes) instead of a copy of it. In fact it may need more memory using the List of `DateTime`.

So Memory shouldn't be a problem like others pointed out.

As to visibility from Binding. If you include a publicy accesible property for the object you will be able to see it.

If your collection of `Class1` object can change however, you should consider implementing `ObservableCollection` also, to tell WPF when the collection changes.